# A standalone (not-cloud based) task management and timing app

Tags: windows, project-management, time-management

I'm wanting a task and time management app for use at work.

Ideally the app should not be cloud-based - as:

1. I don't need to be taking work home with me.
2. I don't want to have to worry about sensitive material being leaked through it.

The app should have the following features:

- Can create a task backlog.
- Tasks can be organised in to projects/labels.
- Supports Pomodoro or similar timing, with a clear label of what task I'm working on.

  - i.e. it would be nice nice if the app can show a breakdown of the day, with what tasks I've worked on, and how long it has taken.
- When a Pomodoro or break is finished - very prominant flashing screen.
- Doesn't talk to the internet / Doesn't need to talk to the internet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[EDIT: Discontinued]

Try my Portable Kanban. Disclosure: I'm developer of PK.

- it works offline
- it's free, can be used commercially.
- it works on Windows only.
- It has a Pomodoro timer that is configurable (work/short pause/long pause intervals, sound)
- It has a lot of options for configuring UI and board.
- May be used for teams too (requires Redis server).

Here's a screenshot of the task backlog:

[image: Portable Kanban]

Comment: This is great! Exactly what I need. The one feature request I'd love to see - is it logging day by day, how much time you spend on each task - if you are using the timer function.

Comment: It's already there: "Setup/Options/Timer/Enable time tracking".

Comment: I think the domain tha tyou link to has changed hands.  It's a page in some form of Asian characters now.  I searched for "portable kanban" and found a softpedia page, but nothing else that looks relevant.  Is this software still supported?

Comment: Note: Development stopped in early 2018, the website closed around 7/2018 – so sadly this software is no longer available. @Dmitry if you're still around and have an updated link, please provide it.